# What happened to the popup dialog in asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fairly new to mvc and I tried mvc4 when it was still in beta.  I remember that when I started a new internet project, I got a popup dialog for log in and registration by default.  I don't see that when I start a new project anymore, is that gone from the internet project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the popup dialog you're referring to was just the jQuery UI Dialog that the sample project used to use:

[image: Dialog]

The project was built to support both a straight request to `/Login` and one via the jQuery UI dialog which was slimmed down to look like it was only a popup. It did this by making the  `Login` action return a different `View` based on it being requested through the frame or not as detected by a value in the query string.

You can of course have this again, you'll just need to do it manually (or dig out one of the older templates) as it's no longer in the default templates.

To help you out, here's a couple of somewhat related questions that contain the sample code (`ContextDependentView` is one thing I remember from this template) and probably some hints on how to recreate it:

1. [Generating a modal jQuery partial view with MVC4 does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294999/generating-a-modal-jquery-partial-view-with-mvc4-does-not-work)
2. [ASP.NET MVC 4 and ContextDependentView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594355/asp-net-mvc-4-and-contextdependentview)
3. [MVC4 - ContextDependentView - What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096735/mvc4-contextdependentview-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 1):

It was removed from the Internet project templates in the final releases of MVC 4.  The popup was pretty slick but I imagine there were issues/complexities they decided to eliminate by just keeping the view/page for logon and registration. In the older versions that had the pop-up they still had the view/page for logon because of how forms based authentication works. If the user is not authenticated/authorized for a web site/page MVC does a redirect to the logon page. This will not work with a JQuery popup dialog on the same page. The popup only worked if you clicked on the Logon link for the page.  I am guessing that they decided since they need the view/page logon anyway to simplify things and keep it consistent by eliminating the popup dialog.

I have implemented an MVC [Single Page Application (SPA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) that only uses a JQuery dialog for a popping up a dialog for logon, and eliminates the need for logon page. But it required a fair amount of customization to authentication/authorization process on the server and used [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on the client.